# Google analytics 4 internal traffic is not filtered

Tags: google-analytics-4

We have connected our website using tag manager to Google Analytics 4. I have defined internal traffic using the data streams and data settings filter.

When I open website pages, I still can see the traffic in our realtime as well as debug view of GA4. Wondering why my traffic is not filtered by GA4

Website address: `animascoaching.com`

Need my traffic filtered in GA4

Comment: Did you make sure to set the filter to active? Or is it set to testing? Have you verified that the `traffic_type` parameter is being set correctly?

Comment: Hello @A_Patterson Filter is active and where should I verify traffic_type parameter

Comment: `traffic_type` can be a custom dimension since it is now being passed along with all user data. If your filter is active, I would check how you are matching your IP addresses. If your traffic is still coming through, it could be your matching pattern.

Comment: Hello @A_Patterson my filter is active and I am matching my IP  address like IP address equals 119.160.64.244. I also used IP address contains 119.160 and IP address begins this 119.160 but none worked for me. I see the traffic from the same IP even on active filter

Comment: Re verifying the traffic_type event parameter, is it set correctly if you look at the data in bigquery?